# How to get an application's process name?

Tags: c#

I am trying to develop a sample application that finds the process name of a particular application.. Suppose there is an application by name **XYZ.exe**.. But when the **XYZ.exe** application is executed, it is not necessary that it holds the same process name.. Let the application run under the process name **abc.exe**..

Now my question is this.. Is it possible to find the process name of **XYZ.exe**?

Any help would much appreciated...

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: Are you trying to locate a running executable that was renamed before being run?

Comment: Ya, even that case is included... But even otherwise, an executable can have a name that is not the process name right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simple:

```
foreach (Process pr in Process.GetProcesses())
{
     try
     {
         Console.WriteLine("App Name: {0}, Process Name: {1}", Path.GetFileName(pr.MainModule.FileName), pr.ProcessName);
     }
     catch { }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lukas,
Thanks a lot for your reply... I shall try this solution and get back to u...

Comment: This code will not print all processes. `pr.MainModule.FileName` can throw an exception. So, on the `catch` block consider add `Console.WriteLine("Process Name: {0}", pr.ProcessName);`