# How to get the appname from process C#

Tags: c#

I am able to get the processes running on Windows with the Process class than I filter theme so that they have a window open. 
However I don't need the process name but the App's name. e.g. The process name of Microsoft Office Word is WINWORD but I want to get Word.

I tried:

```
proc.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.ProductName
```

This works very poorly e.g. the process name of Visual Studio is denenv and the above function returns MicrosoftR Visual StudioR. Not to mention it crashes on Word. So is there a way to get the app name from the process name.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14483264). But i guess it would get you the same result. No harm in trying though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an application's process name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712802/how-to-get-an-applications-process-name)

Comment: Perhaps you need `FileDescription` instead `ProductName`. For instance, product name for Word is 'Microsoft Office 20..' but the file description is 'Microsoft Word'. For Visual Studio file description is 'Microsoft Visual Studio'. On the other hand, what you see on the taskbar are the window's names, not the process names. So for Word, it could be 'Document1 - Word'. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  You don't prefer it when you need to grovel through 64-bit modules.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wpf application project ,add these code to the MainWindow.cs, and add a break point as the instruction.(This works on using a Microsoft Visual Studio IDE.Mine is Visual Studio 2015.)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Process> ProcList = new List<Process>();
        ProcList = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
    }//Add break point here.
}
```

After hitting the break point, move your mouse over the 'ProcList'. You can see all the member of it by clicking at the little triangle button.By re-doing this, you can see all the public member of the Process class, and find whatever you want.

I find a few properties that may help.

```
Process.ProcessName
Process.MainModule.FileName
Process.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileName
Process.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.InternalName
Process.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription
```

Hope it could help.